# What's the knockout equivalent of jQuery.active?

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, knockout.js

In my c# selenium webdriver tests I use

```
public void WaitForJQuery(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
}
```

This waits up until the specified 'timeout' for jQuery calls to finish. I was wondering if there was an equivalent I could use for the knockout.js library?

This question came close, except that it's for q.js: [Equivalent behaviour of 'jQuery.active' in q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16280704/481635)

I'm only just beginning with knockout, and the resources I've found talk about custom bindings and such, but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: What is it your are trying to do? What do you want to wait for?

Comment: After letting selenium execute for example a mouseclick, I want to wait for knockout to be done processing that change to the viewmodel before letting selenium check some assertions. Previously I simply used a timeout of say 500ms, with a lot of tests this takes a lot of time, plus that under load 500ms might not be enough. I don't want race conditions in my tests so I use the deterministic way of checking jQuery.active. Now I'm wondering if there's an equivalent of that in knockout.

Comment: What about subscribing to the observable you are interested in. For example, if a click event updates a certain observable, subscribe to changes in that observable. When the change happens, do what you need to do.

Comment: I'm not interested in a single observable, I want my selenium test to not do anything while knockout is running. And then when knockout is done, _then_ I want selenium to proceed. During my tests knockout is running after every action, I don't think subscribing to every single one of them is the best/fastest(in terms of development time) course of action.